# How can I update the X-Axis and Series ranges of a chart with app script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I have a Google sheet with a table that gets a new entry every day.
Based on the new entry I would like to update 8 charts. I first expected that the charts update automatically using a range like A5:A. But this doesn't work. Charts are sometimes get updated and sometimes not in a random way.

Therefore I try to set the new ranges via a script like this (the ranges array contains the correct new ranges). This script works and updates the ranges as expected.

```
function updateChartRanges(sheet, chart, type, ranges) {
    var newChart;
    var series;

    if (type === 'column') {
      series = {
        0:{targetAxisIndex:1},
        1:{targetAxisIndex:0},
        2:{targetAxisIndex:0},
        3:{targetAxisIndex:0}
      }
      newChart = chart.modify()
        .clearRanges()
        .addRange(ranges[0])
        .addRange(ranges[1])
        .addRange(ranges[2])
        .addRange(ranges[3])
        .setOption("series",series)
        .build();
    } else {
      series = {
        0:{targetAxisIndex:1},
        1:{targetAxisIndex:0},
        2:{targetAxisIndex:0},
        3:{targetAxisIndex:0},
        4:{targetAxisIndex:0},
      }
      newChart = chart.modify()
        .clearRanges()
        .addRange(ranges[0])
        .addRange(ranges[1])
        .addRange(ranges[2])
        .addRange(ranges[3])
        .addRange(ranges[4])
        .setOption("series",series)        
        .build();      
    }      

    sheet.updateChart(newChart);

    logRanges(newChart,'Ranges After');
    
    // Make sure the Charts are shown correctly
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
  }
```

But just setting the ranges doesn't seem to do the trick. When I edit the chart the series and the x-axis are not set anymore.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation on how I can update a range for the series or X-axis. Is there a way to map ranges to series?

Out of sync Google Sheet after a few days:

[image: Out of sync Google Sheet after a few days]

Google Sheet Screenshot:

[image: Google Sheet Screenshot]

Comment: Is triggering the script using time triggers an option? Let's say daily depending on what time your sheet is updated

Comment: I use a time-based trigger to get the new data via an API and to append a row.

I tested it with the script and I also added the data manually. But in both cases, I see the same issue. The range in the series gets only updated partially. I can't recognize any patterns.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem. Is the issue that the ranges are being set statically while you need them to be dynamic?

Comment: I want to add every day new data and update the charts. I expected it to work out of the box with setting ranges like 'A5:A'. But this wasn't working reliably. Randomly it wasn't working for some of the series.

To fix this I want to have an app script that is getting the new range after adding a row and updating the ranges of all charts. This is working for the ranges, but it doesn't update the x-axis range and the series ranges. My question is: How I can update the x-axis range and the series ranges with an app script?

Workaround: I created enough rows for 10 years.

Comment: How is the new data added? Manualy or by script?

Comment: The data is added via a script that is called by a time-based trigger.

Comment: Hi there @fabkru! Please share the script so we all can take a look.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron I updated the code - which is not working as attended.

Comment: Thank you for the update. In order to better replicate your scenario, could you please share an example Sheet that contains the relevant chart data? Feel free to anonymize the Sheet to protect your personal data.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's ridiculous that nobody on the internet even know that the series may be different from data range. It looks like in the past they were always the same? There is simply no resource on the internet how to add series to match the data range